# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TrustManagerFactory SunX509 implementation not found

Tags: android, restlet, restlet-2.0

i just updated to restlet rc6 from previously rc5. The android app does a simple https call to an externel url.

In rc5 everything worked find, in rc6 i now get the following error:

```
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): Error while handling an HTTP client call
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): [ 08-30 10:03:39.185 15077:0x3aff W/System.err ]
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create SSLContext.
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.ext.net.internal.HttpUrlConnectionCall.<init>(HttpUrlConnectionCall.java:130)
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.ext.net.HttpClientHelper.create(HttpClientHelper.java:156)
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.toSpecific(ClientAdapter.java:160)
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:111)
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:180)
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1137)
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleOutbound(ClientResource.java:1226)
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1069)
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1045)
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:951)
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:658)
08-30 10:03:39.185: WARN/System.err(15077): at de.ewe.tk.apps.android.css.services.DocstoreService.getDocumentInfos(DocstoreService.java:86)
08-30 10:03:39.195: WARN/System.err(15077): at de.ewe.tk.apps.android.css.activity.DocstoreListActivity$GetDocumentInfosTask.doInBackground(DocstoreListActivity.java:66)
08-30 10:03:39.195: WARN/System.err(15077): at de.ewe.tk.apps.android.css.activity.DocstoreListActivity$GetDocumentInfosTask.doInBackground(DocstoreListActivity.java:46)
08-30 10:03:39.195: WARN/System.err(15077): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-30 10:03:39.195: WARN/System.err(15077): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-30 10:03:39.195: WARN/System.err(15077): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-30 10:03:39.195: WARN/System.err(15077): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
08-30 10:03:39.195: WARN/System.err(15077): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
08-30 10:03:39.195: WARN/System.err(15077): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
08-30 10:03:39.195: WARN/System.err(15077): Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TrustManagerFactory SunX509 implementation not found
08-30 10:03:39.195: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:105)
08-30 10:03:39.195: WARN/System.err(15077): at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.java:80)
08-30 10:03:39.195: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.ext.ssl.DefaultSslContextFactory.createSslContext(DefaultSslContextFactory.java:357)
08-30 10:03:39.195: WARN/System.err(15077): at org.restlet.ext.net.internal.HttpUrlConnectionCall.<init>(HttpUrlConnectionCall.java:126)
08-30 10:03:39.195: WARN/System.err(15077): ... 21 more
```

can anyone tell me what has changed in rc6 so that it is not working anymore?

the release notes for rc6 say:

```
The support for HTTPS has been significantly completed and fixed in all connectors for :

cipher suites restriction
SSL/TLS protocol version restriction
client certificate request & requirement setting
```

unfortunately i didn´t find any hints in the official docs what to change in my code in order to get it working again.

thanx,
thilo

Answer (score 3):

The silly bunnies included the following in the `DefaultSslContextFactory.createSslContext(..)` method for rc6 apparently:

```
setKeyManagerAlgorithm(helperParameters.getFirstValue(
            "keyManagerAlgorithm", true, System.getProperty(
                    "ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm", "SunX509")));
```

I.e. they hardcoded SunX509 which is proprietary to the Sun JDK - a pretty bad idea overall. This was fixed in the commit `025d356d9fc3620ba9ed613fed32f1a5668f4f70`, 17 days ago.

If you need it to work *now* you could try downloading and building the libraries yourself of course.

Comment: What is the proper way to configure this on Android then?

Comment: The "latest" source should work, they've removed the direct reference to SunX509 at least.

Comment: hm, i just updated to version 2.1.0 which was release on 09/20/2012. The exception is still the same:
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TrustManagerFactory SunX509 implementation not found

Comment: A workaround is to set the following property:
`System.setProperty( "ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm", javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())`
This is working for me.